# bootstrapx-clickover HTML content?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using [Bootstrapx-Clickover](http://www.leecarmichael.com/bootstrapx-clickover/examples.html)

Running this javascript for the clickover:

```
var message = "Access Forbidden.</br> <a href=\"/contact/access\">Request Access!</a>";
$("#spec").clickover({placement:'top', title: "Sensitive information", content: message, width: 170, height: 110});
```

The HTML content wont render:

[image]

It used to work with **bootstrap 2.1**, but now i upgrade to **2.2**.

Any ideas?

Comment: Maybe the malformed <br /> tag is being rejected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated in [this issue](https://github.com/lecar-red/bootstrapx-clickover/issues/25), you need to add `html: true` to your clickover options.

```
$("#spec").clickover({placement:'top', title: "Sensitive information", content: message, width: 170, height: 110, html: true});
```